# .NET WebForms application session information not available to MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I started with a WebForms .NET 4.51 application. I then added WebAPI to the same application. In Session_Start() I create a variable instance that I store within the session as follows:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
        protected void Session_Start(object aSender, EventArgs aEventArgs)
        {            
            //Create an object to hold all the settings for the user in the session. This is only loaded once we 
            //have a user successfully logged in
            HttpContext.Current.Session[SYSTEM_SETTINGS_SESSION_KEY] = new SystemSettings();
        }
}
```

and I have a simple property accessor as follows:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
  public static SystemSettings SystemSettings
  {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current == null)
                    return null;

                return HttpContext.Current.Session[SYSTEM_SETTINGS_SESSION_KEY] as SystemSettings;
            }
        }
}
```

The above all works well when I am accessing the property from code **except** when I attempt to do this from within a WebAPI controller as follows via the property from above viz *Global.SystemSettings*:

```
public class EmailActivitiesController : ApiController
{
  emailBody = EmailToClientsTemplateBuilderHelper.TemplateContentBuild(emailBody, Global.SystemSettings);
}
```

When I inspect *HttpContext.Current.Session* it is ***NULL***.

So why is the Session collection null when accessed from the WebAPI controller?

I need to store use the information related to the user's session in the WebAPI controller, so do I need to store things differently now?

**UPDATE**

The accepted solution also worked for WebAPI 1 which is what the application is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because **WebApi** does not have `Session` enabled by default. **WebApi** is trying to  encourage you to move towards **stateless HTTP** and **RESTful APIs**.

I strongly urge you to rework your design without sessions.

With this said, you can enable Session in WebApi 2 by adding this to Global.asax

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest() 
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(
        System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

Comment: I hear you about no sessions, unfortunately this app has a few years behind it already and makes use of sessions quite heavily.